# Can an Airline ban me for getting a refund through a chargeback?

Tags: payment-cards, fees-and-charges

I booked an airline ticket and I think I selected the correct travel date, but due to some technical glitch the wrong date was selected and I paid for the ticket which is non-refundable. Immediately after getting the itinerary I called the airline helpline and lodged a complaint but they wouldn't fix the date. I was infuriated and called the credit card company to get a chargeback. I won the chargeback.

Can that airline blacklist me and the people that I booked tickets for? I am not interested in traveling with them again, but can they also get me blacklisted on other airlines?

Comment: What country? In the US all tickets are refundable within 24 hours so you could have just refunded it since you noticed immediately

Comment: Not US, some where in South East Asia.

Comment: And why do you think they won't challenge the chargeback and win?

Comment: The transaction was reversed by the credit card company. This also means they failed to come up with an evidence.

Comment: @FurqanHashim Not necessarily. It’s credit card industry practice to refund the chargeback *provisionally* while reserving the right to claw the refund back should ongoing investigation/communication with the airline company show that your chargeback claim is invalid. https://www.chargebackgurus.com/blog/chargeback-process

Comment: Chargeback is not a refund, it's claiming the merchant had no right to your payment in the first place. You may have been right, but the airline doesn't believe so.

Comment: It's claiming the airline stole your money. That's a big claim, and if they didn't steal it, you can go to jail for fraud for saying they stole it. (Probably not, if it was just a mistake - but you could)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, as a rule of thumb using a chargeback against any merchant will get you blacklisted from that merchant.

**No**, they can't blacklist you anywhere else, and in practice they will find it difficult to even keep you blacklisted: if you use a different payment method and/or a slight variation of your name, they're unlikely to be able to match you.

Comment: do you have a source backing this up?

Comment: @njzk2 Here's one: https://www.seattletimes.com/life/travel/travel-wise-heres-what-can-get-you-banned-by-airlines-hotels-and-rental-car-companies/